# Increment Number In a String + 1

Tags: python

I put together python script which will read the string "BatchSequence="NUMBER INCREMENT HERE" and just return the integers. How can i find a certain integer and increment the rest by one but leaving the integers before the same? It skips 3 and goes to 5. I want it to go 3,4,5.

Also,
Once i have figured this script out. How can i replace the numbers of the original text file with the new script numbers? Would i have to write into a new file?

I have tried increment the numbers by one but it starts from the beginning.

code that i tried:

```
import re

file = '\\\MyDataNEE\\user$\\bxt058y\\Desktop\\75736.oxi.error'

counter = 0
for line in open(file):
    match = re.search('BatchSequence="(\d+)"', line)
    if match:
        print(int(match.group(1)) + 1)
```

Original Code:

```
import re

file = 'FILENAME HERE'

counter = 0
for line in open(file):
    match = re.search('BatchSequence="(\d+)"', line)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Currently:

```
BatchSequence="1"
BatchSequence="2"
BatchSequence="3"
BatchSequence="5"
BatchSequence="6"
BatchSequence="7"
BatchSequence="8"
```

New output should be:

```
BatchSequence="1"
BatchSequence="2"
BatchSequence="3"
BatchSequence="4"
BatchSequence="5"
BatchSequence="6"
BatchSequence="7"
```

Comment: What is in the input file?

Comment: If you want to use your own numbers, you need to completely ignore whatever number was in the file. You have a good start towards that, but notice that "counter" is completely unused in your code. To write your changes to disk, yes, you will want to rewrite the file (preferably write to temp, then swap, then delete original)

Answer (score 0):

My take on the problem:

```
txt = '''BatchSequence="1"
BatchSequence="2"
BatchSequence="3"
BatchSequence="5"
BatchSequence="6"
BatchSequence="7"
BatchSequence="8"'''

import re

def fn(my_number):
    val = yield
    while True:
        val = yield str(val) if val < my_number else str(val-1)

f = fn(4)
next(f)
s = re.sub(r'BatchSequence="(\d+)"', lambda g: 'BatchSequence="' + f.send(int(g.group(1))) + '"', txt)

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
BatchSequence="1"
BatchSequence="2"
BatchSequence="3"
BatchSequence="4"
BatchSequence="5"
BatchSequence="6"
BatchSequence="7"
```

The function `fn(my_number)` will return same values until it reaches `my_number`, then the values are decremented by one.